# How to find out who did create/change a content type in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

Over 5 years ago somebody did ask a similar question for SP 2010 ([How can I see who created WebSite content type?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/131373/how-can-i-see-who-created-website-content-type)) - I can't believe that such a feature is not available today - in SP online - so daring to kinda re-post the question:

How can you find out who is the author of a custom content type?

I mean isn't everything in SP stored in SQL database? Isn't everything an "element"? Isn't a content type a (system) element as well? Shouldn't this information be available for every "element" in some table? I am pretty new to this sharepoint thing - only no-code/low-code people tell me - but seems it isn't ready for industrial usage yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can find who has created or modified a content type by [searching the audit log via the compliance center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?view=o365-worldwide#search-the-audit-log): https://protection.office.com/unifiedauditlog.

Select the activities you want, in this scenario, `Created site content type` and `Updated list content type` under **Activities**, fill in other information you want to specific.  Click **Search** and you will get the related activities on Content Types.

Please note that all objects including Content Types will return as `ObjectId` instead of display names. You can then navigate to the content type via this link: `/_layouts/15/ManageContentType.aspx?ctype=ObjectId`.

[image]

[image]